# Best method to preload images in a Sencha/jQuery application?

Tags: jquery, extjs

The traditional method being loading images using *new Images()* function. But is there any other method which is better than this one to load image at the time of data ?

Or specifically, what is the best method to load images in a scenario, where let say I am populating a Sencha List component using Name and Image as list item, where I get Name and Image URL from the server ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Sencha but in that scenario you can simply put the image tags in the container.
The browser will start to download all the images in chunks (which size is browser dependent).

If you need a method to load images **even faster** you could use an old *trick*: specify different 3rd level domains for images. like img1.domain.com, img2.domain.com, ...
This way the browser parallelize the loading. Of course for this method you need complete control over the webserver too.